# dinamic horizontal alignment - responsive columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am coding a website that contains a ul list with responsive columns. Depending on the window's size, the column width will shrink or expand. I want the text contained inside the li element to center-align (horizontally) according to the new column width. 
you will be able to see the real page on this example: 
http://studiomk27.com.br/portfolio/html/e_residencial.html

I want the code to recognize the browser's window size and consider this variable width to recalculate the li element position, so it will be placed in the middle of the column. is it a good idea to use some javascript? Not sure how, tho

THE HTML:

```
<div class="gridresidencial">
<ul class="img-list">


<div class="grid-item" id="q5">
  <li>
    <a href="residencial_casanamata.html">
       <figure>
        <img src="../img/mini_casanamata.jpg" alt="">
        <span class="text-content"><span><h2>CASA</h2>NA MATA</span></span>
       </figure>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>  

<div class="grid-item" id="q4">
  <li>
     <a href="residencial_casadabahia.html">
         <figure>
         <img src="../img/mini_casadabahia.jpg" alt="">
         <span class="text-content"><span><h2>CASA</h2> DA BAHIA </span ></span>
         </figure>
     </a>
   </li>
 </div>

 <div class="grid-item" id="q7">
    <li>
     <a href="residencial_cobogo.html">
      <figure>
        <img src="../img/mini_cobogo.jpg" alt="">
        <span class="text-content"><span><h2>CASA</h2> COBOGÓ </span></span>
      </figure>
      </a>
   </li>
 </div>

</ul>
</div>
```

THE CSS:

```
.gridresidencial {
  margin-top: calc(1.25% + 180px); 
  width:101.5%;
  padding:0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1930px) {
.img-list {  float: none;columns: 4;}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1285px) and (max-width:1930px) {
.img-list { float: none;columns: 3;}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width:1285px)  {
.img-list { float: none; columns: 2;}}

.img-list {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 0px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 0px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
        text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float:none;
  position: relative;
}

li figure {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;
}

.img-list img{
  float: right;
  max-height:560px;
  max-width:1280px; 
  margin:0;
  width:645px;
  height: 285px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1930px) {
 span.text-content { 
      float: center;
      columns: 4;
      margin-left:15px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

 span.text-content {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 320px;
  margin-top:50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size:40px;
  font-family: "AktivGroteskStdBd";
  line-height: 0.6;
}

h2 {text-align: center;}

ul:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand weel, you wan to center the items everytime ?

If yes you can do this :

```
.gridresidencial {
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: as long as i tried, if i do this way, the columns will not be responsive! (they wont shrink, they will only change on page break) is there a way to center all items and turn them into responsive?

Comment: First I just saw a mistake : your div grid-item should be inside the <li>. Second, your image seems to be very big, is it normal ? And can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and post your code  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ul.img-list li {
   width:100%;
}
```

also try to remove **margin-top** from **span.text-content** class